# None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

while pushing spring boot application on pivotal cloud foundry , app got staged but throw exception of incompatible javabuildpack version.I have three questions

1.with cf buildpacks I got the list of buildpacks but how to figure out the version of java_buildpack present in pcf

2.How to create the custom buildpack as per the java version used in app.

3.How to check the compatibility of java buildpack with our app.

Comment: What is the exact error you're seeing? What is the exact `cf push` command you're running? What type of Java app are you running? java main, spring boot, WAR, etc..

Comment: @Daniel I am getting the below error -   buildpack.git#553f2c6
   [Buildpack]  ERROR Finalize failed with exception #<RuntimeError: No container can run this application. No container can run this application. Please ensure that you've pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid JVM artifacts can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation.   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 1   Exit status 223

Comment: Command used is - cf push -f manifest.yml

Comment: I am trying to push the Spring Boot application as JAR

Comment: What's in your manifest.yml?

Comment: @DanielMikusa - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774751/spring-cloud-foundry-issue-223 ?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `cf buildpacks` it should tell you the buildpack version in the filename column. Something like:

```
buildpack        position   enabled   locked   filename
java_buildpack   1          true      false    java-buildpack-offline-cflinuxfs2-v4.13.1.zip
```

So this would be buildpack version 4.13.1.

Basically whatever versions you have uploaded or available in `cf buildpacks` are just what an app would choose from if not specifically set. You can specifically set a version in your application manifest though:

```
---
applications:
- name: myapp-ui
  host: myapp-ui
  memory: 1G
  path: build/libs/myapp-ui-v0.2-gf55cb31.jar
  buildpack: 'https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#v3.19.2'
```

When done this way, the staging will ignore whatever buildpacks are available and will download the specific version from the web. You could also upload the buildpack version you need using a unique name and reference it directly in the manifest:

```
cf create-buildpack java-buildpack-v3 https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/releases/download/v3.19.2/java-buildpack-v3.19.2.zip 99 --enable

---
applications:
- name: myapp-ui
  host: myapp-ui
  memory: 1G
  path: build/libs/myapp-ui-v0.2-gf55cb31.jar
  buildpack: java-buildpack-v3
```